# Django 1.4 deploy issue

Tags: django, apache

I did a build out  For my Project muvidb_backup .

In bin folder has the django.wsgi file

This file look like :

```
import sys
sys.path[0:0] = [
  '/home/abhilash/Documents/muvidb_backup/eggs/ipython-0.13.1-py2.7.egg',
    '/home/abhilash/Documents/muvidb_backup/eggs/django_grappelli-2.4.3-py2.7.egg',
    '/home/abhilash/Documents/muvidb_backup/eggs/django_markitup-0.5.2-py2.7.egg',
    '/home/abhilash/Documents/muvidb_backup/eggs/django_robots-0.7.0-py2.7.egg',
    '/home/abhilash/Documents/muvidb_backup/eggs/django_filebrowser-3.5.1-py2.7.egg',
    '/home/abhilash/Documents/muvidb_backup/eggs/BeautifulSoup-3.2.0-py2.7.egg',
    '/home/abhilash/Documents/muvidb_backup/eggs/Markdown-2.2.1-py2.7.egg',
    '/home/abhilash/Documents/muvidb_backup/eggs/djangorecipe-1.3-py2.7.egg',
    '/home/abhilash/Documents/muvidb_backup/eggs/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg',
    '/home/abhilash/Documents/muvidb_backup/eggs/zc.recipe.egg-1.3.2-py2.7.egg',
    '/home/abhilash/Documents/muvidb_backup/eggs/zc.buildout-1.6.3-py2.7.egg',
    '/home/abhilash/Documents/muvidb_backup/eggs/setuptools-0.6c12dev_r88846-py2.7.egg',
    '/home/abhilash/Documents/muvidb_backup',
  ]

import djangorecipe.wsgi

application = djangorecipe.wsgi.main('muvidb_backup.development', logfile='')
```

And My Apache config file is :

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
DocumentRoot "/home/abhilash/Documents/muvidb_backup"
<Directory "/home/abhilash/Documents/muvidb_backup">
    allow from all

    Options +Indexes
</Directory>

Alias /static/admin/ "/home/abhilash/Documents/muvidb_backup/muvidb_backup/static/admin"


WSGIScriptAlias / /home/abhilash/Documents/muvidb_backup/bin/django.wsgi
</VirtualHost>
```

My Seetings.py file

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static')


STATIC_URL = '/static/'


ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'
```

Why Localhost:8080/admin/ is not loading admin css and js files ??

in static folfer i have admin/css and js folders .

More over in url.py i have a snap code to get static files

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
     {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
     {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
)
```

Can any one Help me ???

Comment: Why are you asking about `localhost:8080` if this is a deployment issue? That's the address for the development server. Which is it?

Comment: did you do a manage.py collectstatic?

Comment: I did python manage.py collectstatic [bin/django collectstatic for buildout ]

Comment: i am deploying it on my localhost system (accessible throw LAN connection using my IP 192.168.2.54:8080 ) @Daniel Roseman